# How to produce nested matrix with labels just using the amsmath package?

Tags: amsmath, matrices, labels, nesting

I am trying to create this matrix in `Microsoft word 2010` with `mathtype` and since `mathtype` just uses the `amsmath` package, I should only use this pckage in my `latex` code. Can anyone tell me what code should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can, with some tricks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\boldsymbol{O}_{4}(2\phi)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \mspace{-12mu} \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} &
\mspace{-12mu}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \vphantom{\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}}
  \boldsymbol{O}_{3}(2\phi)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The main trick is nesting matrices; but it's also necessary to compensate the space of the inner left bracket, which I do with the `\mspace{-12mu}` commands.

[image]

Comment: can you please explain more about this line? `\vphantom{\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}}` what does `vphantom` do? also from `\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}` seems that you have created a 3x1 matrix as the inner matrix not a 3x3 matrix?!!!

Comment: @sepideh The phantom makes the inner `bmatrix` as high as the column of zeros; the outer `bmatrix` has two columns.

Comment: I mean the inner bmatrix has just 1 column

Comment: @sepideh Yes, of course: you just want one object in it, don't you?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution, based on `blkarray`, `multirow` and `\bigstrut`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{blkarray, multirow, bigstrut}

\newcommand\mystrut[1][0.6ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[t]}}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\[ \bm{O}_4(2\phi) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\!\!\!\begin{blockarray}{c c c c}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \mystrut\\
    \begin{block}{c [c c c]}
    0 & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{$\bm{O}_3(2\phi)$}}\\
    0 & \\
    0 &\\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\!\vspace{-1.8ex} \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]