# small matrix inside big matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays, tikz-matrix

How can put a matrix inside a matrix like the picture shown with a big letter inside the smaller one?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far ...

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the `nicematrix` package. There are examples with code on the creation of this type of matrices.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261479

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution builds on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261484/5001) by @egreg; the main difference is in the use of `\vcenter` to vertically center the `\huge$R$` element.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' and 'bmatrix' environments
\newcommand\myvec{\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}}
\begin{document}

\[
\Lambda(R)=
\begin{bmatrix} % start of outer 'bmatrix' env.
1 & \mspace{-10mu} 
  \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \\
\myvec & \mspace{-10mu}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \vphantom{\myvec}
    \vcenter{\hbox{\hspace*{7pt}\huge$R$\hspace*{7pt}}} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\scriptscriptstyle 4\times4}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[ \Lambda(R) = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \Block{3-3}<\Huge>{R} \\
0 & \\
0 & 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{2-2}{4-4}]
\end{bNiceMatrix}_{4 \times 4}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]